# Docker Swarm with GlusterFS as the external volume storage and VIP

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cluster-computing, glusterfs, pacemaker

I was wondering if Docker Swarm was possible to be a load balancer with GlusterFS as the local filesystem? And use Pacemaker to hold the VIP (because I understand Docker cannot create a VIP).

My idea - which I'm hoping can be verified or suggested better :)

System:

```
2x CentOS 8 servers
- 192.168.0.1
---- /dev/sda (OS)
---- /dev/sdb (data)
- 192.168.0.2
---- /dev/sda (OS)
---- /dev/sdb (data)
```

1. Install Pacemaker, Corosync

   ```
   dnf --enablerepo=HighAvailability -y install pacemaker pcs psmisc policycoreutils-python-utils
   systemctl start pcsd
   ```
2. Add a VIP to both servers

   ```
    pcs resource create vip IPaddr2 ip=192.168.0.100 cidr_netmask=24 op monitor interval=30s
   ```
3. Set up both storage

   ```
    mkfs.xfs /dev/sdb
   ```
4. Make the directory and add to startup

   ```
    mkdir -p /my-data/

    echo "/dev/sdb /my-data xfs defaults 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
   ```
5. Install GlusterFS on both nodes

   ```
    dnf install -y glusterfs-server
   ```
6. Setup Gluster for the volume

   ```
    gluster volume create gfs replica 2 transport tcp node01:/my-data node02:/my-data force
    gluster volume start gfs
   ```
7. Make it accessible for the replication

   ```
    echo 'node01:/my-data /mnt glusterfs defaults,_netdev 0 0' >> /etc/fstab

    echo 'node02:/my-data /mnt glusterfs defaults,_netdev 0 0' >> /etc/fstab
   ```
8. Install Docker and Docker-Compose
9. Initialise Swarm

   ```
    - on node01 use IP 192.168.0.1 -> manager
    - on node02 use IP 192.168.0.2 -> manager
   ```
10. Create the directories

    ```
     mkdir /mnt/html
     mkdir /mnt/mysql
    ```
11. In the docker-compose.yml file:

    ```
    volumes:
        - "/mnt/html:/var/www/html/wp-content"
    volumes:
        - "/mnt/mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
    ```
12. Apart of the docker-compose.yml - apache:

    ```
    Use IP 192.168.0.100 as the access on 80
    ```

My thoughts are that as 192.168.0.100 is only accessible on one of the Pacemaker resources, that the secondary Manager wouldn't be hit on the front end. If that node went down on the IP .100 then the other node02 would take that IP and the Swarm would still be active.

Is this something that would work? I cant find anything about having a VIP on the Swarm - at least working solutions.

I have them both as Managers because I assume if the manager goes off then its not going to work? Then if I had a 3rd, 4th, etc. I'd add them as Workers.